# Did Spirit Airlines break the law when they sold me Wi-Fi that they do not offer on any of their planes?

Tags: consumer-protection

On the 29th of September I flew from PDX to Las Vegas and bought the Wi-Fi service that was offered online to utilize during the flight. I further learned the Spirit Airlines has no Wi-Fi anywhere on any flight. I've been trying for the last 5 days to get a hold of somebody to issue me a refund and I get is the answer no

Comment: Break the law, as in criminal?  Almost certainly not.  Did they breach a contract by selling you something that they were unable to provide?  Probably.  But a lot depends on the specific contract that you agreed to and the laws that govern the jurisdiction you are in or that the flight covered.  Possibly Oregon, Nevada, or United States.  You might just dispute that portion of the charge with your credit card company, who will likely give you a refund and you can be done with it.

Comment: Insofar as they explain how to tell which flights have Wi-Fi, and many PDX-LAS flights claim to have it now, how did you learn that they have no WiFi on any flight?

Comment: You did not specify who you bought it from. It is not believable that Spirit does this if they don't have Wi-Fi available on any of their flights. It is much more believable that a shady Travel Agent would do something like this.

Comment: who sold you this wifi exactly?  I have troubnle believing they sell a product they don't provide ever.  Was this from something like Priceline?

Answer (score 5):

Given the facts as stated in the question, it appears that Spirit owes a refund. If the portal or site through which the service was sold also handles other flights that do provide wi-fi, there may not have been an intention to sell an unavailable service, and so this may not have been fraud.

It is not proper to knowingly sell a service that is not available, but if it is an error, it is not strictly illegal, but the contract has not been fulfilled.

One could, in such a case, attempt to place a charge-back with the credit card through which payment was made, if a card was used. Failing that, one could take the matter to small claims court. Before opening a court case, I would send a physical letter by certified mail to the airline's customer service address, with a copy to its HQ address, explaining what happened and requesting a refund by a specified date. If there is a customer service email, a copy to that as well.